# split python string without empty strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

The following code:

```
str = 'Welcome\nto\nPythonExamples\nWelcome\nto\nPythonExamples'
chunks = str.split('\n')
print(chunks)
```

Correctly prints out:

```
['Welcome', 'to', 'PythonExamples', 'Welcome', 'to', 'PythonExamples']
```

I want to split the string into strings that start with **'Welcome\n'**  so I have tried the following:

```
str = 'Welcome\nto\nPythonExamples\nWelcome\nto\nPythonExamples'
chunks = str.split('Welcome\n')
print(chunks)
```

But this prints out:

```
['', 'to\nPythonExamples\n', 'to\nPythonExamples']
```

Notice how the first entry is empty.
How can I split it up correctly so that the output is?

```
['to\nPythonExamples\n', 'to\nPythonExamples']
```

Comment: remove the empty string via a comphrension?

Comment: Just to clarify, the only thing that bothers you are the empty strings that might come up?

Comment: I assumed that because the empty string is there then I am parsing it incorrectly.  I wonder why the empty value is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to avoid empty strings.
You can just use list comprehension, do this:

```
chunks = [x for x in str.split('Welcome\n') if x]
```

Should solve your problem. Why?

First of all, the list comprehension adds `if x` in the end, this means that it will include in the list only *truthy* values (or rather, will omit falsy values).

But why did you get `''` in the first place? It would be the easier to point you at the [source code for `split`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/459cd61399f589caccae1c0fa2138ebcaaa63ea6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L165):

```
while (maxcount-- > 0) {
    pos = FASTSEARCH(str+i, str_len-i, sep, sep_len, -1, FAST_SEARCH);
    if (pos < 0)
        break;
    j = i + pos;
    SPLIT_ADD(str, i, j);
    i = j + sep_len;
}
```

Basically, split function looks for the next occurrence of `sep` in `split(sep)` and derives a substring from last occurrence to pos(it would do it `maxcount` times). Since you got `Welcome\n` in pos 0 and your "last occurence" is 0, it will make a substring from 0 to 0 which results in an empty string.

By the way, you would also get empty string for such string:

> 'Welcome\nWelcome\nto\nPythonExamples\nWelcome\nto\nPythonExamples'

results for your code, without my change:

> ['', '', 'to\nPythonExamples\n', 'to\nPythonExamples']

Comment: Do you know why the first entry is empty ?

Comment: Sure, let me add that to the answer

Comment: @HarryBoy, I've added this part to my answer. Let me know if you have any more questions :) GL

Answer (score 2):

You could filter out the empty entries. Also avoid using `str` as it is a builtin function. Since `''` is falsy you don't even need a comparison.

```
inp = 'Welcome\nto\nPythonExamples\nWelcome\nto\nPythonExamples'
chunks = list(filter(None, inp.split('Welcome\n')))
print(chunks)
```

Comment: Using `lambda` in this case is really unnecessary. You can use `filter(None, chunks)` directly.

Comment: Hmm, it might be the case that if it is `None` it implicitly does `lambda x: x` as the function though.

Comment: Interesting it would be better to use none because it is using this in the source code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f18c223391eef8c7d01241b51a7b2429609dd84/Python/bltinmodule.c#L567 so updating it for that improvement

Answer (score 2):

One very clean and Pythonic way would be using [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with `None`. On the side, `str` is keyword in Python, you should not use it as a variable name.

```
text = 'Welcome\nto\nPythonExamples\nWelcome\nto\nPythonExamples'
chunks = text.split('Welcome\n')
chunks = filter(None, chunks)
print(list(chunks))
#['to\nPythonExamples\n', 'to\nPythonExamples']
```

Comment: `chunks = list(filter(None, chunks))` otherwise `chunks` is printed as a filter object.